# How to nodes discover other nodes?

Tags: full-node, nodes

How do nodes/wallets know what is the IP of the "nearby" node running monerod. How do they discover other nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monero wallet's daemon monerod initially and when all recent peers are offline tries to connect to one of the hard coded **seed nodes**, [currently these are](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/4f93f745284c10f12e2524f5211030085d9626cf/src/p2p/net_node.h):

```
seeds.moneroseeds.se
seeds.moneroseeds.ae.org
seeds.moneroseeds.ch
seeds.moneroseeds.li
```

If it peers with enough regular network nodes, these nodes are not used any more unless all known peers are offline.